# Shiny input inside a sweetalert

Tags: r, shiny, sweetalert

I've just find out the package sweetalertR which allows to create really nice alert box.

I would like to use an alert to ask user to fill an input.

The best would be to render inside the alert any ui, but no idea if it is possible or not.

It seems that the sweetalert() comes with a default input option

```
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)
library(sweetalertR)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
         tags$h1("Click the button"),
         actionButton(inputId = "inputbutton", label = "Launch sweet alert input"),
         receiveSweetAlert(messageId = "inputmss") # ,
         # verbatimTextOutput("text")
         ),
    server = function(input, output) {
         observeEvent(input$inputbutton, {
             sendSweetAlert(
                 messageId = "inputmss", title = "Input", text = "Enter text:", type = "input"
             )
         })
         # output$text <- renderPrint({input})
         }
)
```

I don't know how to access in server to the input inside the alert.

It doesn't appear to be recorded by default in shiny "input" (commented lines are this check)

Any idea?

Comment: do you use any additional pacakges? After `install_github("timelyportfolio/sweetalertR")` and loading the library i dont have the function `sendSweetAlert()` etc. available,...

Comment: @BigDataScientist yes you are right I forgot the shinyWidgets package!
I've just edited the code

Comment: did you ask the creater of the package already by any chance. What i find really odd is that there is a function `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('inputmss', function(data) {
  swal({title: data.title, text: data.text, type: data.type, html: data.html})});`, which essentially sends data from the server to the ui. So it would be strange to send it back fom ui to server, as it is at some point apparently available as `data.text`,...

Comment: Did you figure out how to access the sweetalert input value in the server? I would love to know how